# Location Simulation Without Running Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to simulate a location on an iOS device without having to run `Xcode` with `gpx` files to do so? I'm fluent in swift and objc and would like to make an app simulate a location without running Xcode. The down side is that when you want to simulate a location without being connected to `Xcode` the app does not continue to simulate the location. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, you can't do this. It would violate the Sandbox

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any way to do this while violating the Sandbox? I'm not looking to submit it to the app store. I'd like it for personal recreational use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I use a quite ugly hack to do that.

When you have your device connected to the Xcode while simulating location, just remove the lighting cable without killing an app directly.

The app will crash but when you relaunch it you will see it shows the same simualated location despite the fact it's no longer connected to the Xcode.

**Note that this is not an elegant approach** and to make your device location services work properly again, you have to run an app from Xcode on your device and explicitly set `Debug/Simulate Location/Don't Simulate Location`

Comment: That did work! Although, it's not quite what I was looking for because you still have to hook back up to the computer to change the location if you want to simulate a new location. Doing this when not at home or connected to Xcode seems difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately I suppose that is the only way you can simulate location without being connected directly to Xcode.

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you.